# Animating listview data change

Tags: android, listview, animation

I'm working on Android with a set of data(`ArrayList`) that populates a `ListView`. At the moment when I change the sorting mode I re-order the data linked to the adapter and call `notifyOnDataChanged()` to update the list.

This does the job, but I'd like to be able to animate each item to its new position(like on iOS) as both data sets contain the same items - just reordered.

I've spent some time thinking about how I'd animate this and decided to animate all items that appear lower down on the list to a height of zero and then animate back to their normal size in the new position. This would let all items that move up in the data actually move up in the list as items disappear above it. So that's the idea, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

The data could be represented like this:

```
Set A | index | Set B
------+-------+------
A     | 0     | B
B     | 1     | A
C     | 2     | C
D     | 3     | F
E     | 4     | G
F     | 5     | E
G     | 6     | D
```

I'm just looking for something that iOS handles by default for Android. It shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: I'm also really interested in this. Not only re-ordering, but also animating additions/removals.

Comment: did u fix this?I want to knnow the solution.could u please help ??

Answer (score 11):

Made a small example that animates the reordering of such a list. The animation is not exactly as you described but hopefully it helps you achieve what you want.

https://github.com/fabrantes/widgetexamples

The flow is something like this:

1. Save the current state before notifyDataSetChanged(). Saving the state consists in storing the getTop() coordinate for each item.
2. After notifyDataSetChange, go through all the ListView views and apply a TranslateAnimation with the height difference between the new item position and the old position.

Comment: How would you approach adding/removing to the list? Wouldn't it mess the re-ordering?

Comment: I'd really prefer if this would come in a form of a ListView subclass, and if it had support for added/removed items, but hey, thanks for the effort :-)

Comment: Not sure about adding/removing. As for making it a ListView subclass, that should be easy. Create the said subclass and put the required functions inside. Then override notifyDataSetChanged and call those functions there (careful with the order).

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is the solution to your problems

```
  <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listUniversal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layoutAnimation="@anim/controller">

        </ListView>
```

anim.xml

```
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/scale_1"
    android:delay="50%" />
```

scale_1.xml

```
<scale
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXScale="0.1"
    android:fromYScale="0.1"
    android:pivotX="10%"
    android:pivotY="10%"
    android:startOffset="100"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

Comment: Add the namespace to the scale element and perfect! (    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android").

Comment: What about the animation to delete an item from the list? How could I do it?